# Loan amortizarion schedule with schedule dates in java

Tags: java, date

I am attempting to have schedule dates in my Loan schedule but the dates are wrong in that they have skipped some Months:

```
 public static void printAmortizationSchedule(double principal, double annualInterestRate, int numYears) {
        double interestPaid, principalPaid, newBalance;
        double monthlyInterestRate, monthlyPayment;
        int month;
        int numMonths = numYears * 12;

        // Output monthly payment and total payment
        monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12;
        monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment(principal, monthlyInterestRate, numYears);
        System.out.format("Monthly Payment: %8.2f%n", monthlyPayment);
        System.out.format("Total Payment:   %8.2f%n", monthlyPayment * numYears * 12);

        // Print the table header
        printTableHeader();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        for (month = 1; month <= numMonths; month++) {
            // Compute amount paid and new balance for each payment period
            interestPaid = principal * (monthlyInterestRate / 100);
            principalPaid = monthlyPayment - interestPaid;
            newBalance = principal - principalPaid;
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY", Locale.getDefault());
            String dddate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
            // Output the data item
            printScheduleItem(month, dddate, interestPaid, principalPaid, newBalance);

            // Update the balance
            principal = newBalance;
        }
    }
```

print schedule method:

```
 private static void printScheduleItem(int month, String dddate, double interestPaid, double principalPaid, double newBalance) {
        System.out.format("%8d%12s%10.2f%10.2f%12.2f\n",
                month, dddate, interestPaid, principalPaid, newBalance);
    }
```

I am sure the problem is coming in adding the months to the dates how do I resolve that?

Comment: `cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);` should probably be `cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);`

Comment: Also if you need is a date (without time), you should probably use [a `LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instead of `Calendar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);
```

It should be:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```